# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome, parallel-execution

I am running selenium scripts on EC2 instance in headless mode. The scripts run multiple parallel chrome browsers. So 1 out of 3 times I get the following error -

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'new-selenium-jenkins', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-1081-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_342'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 98.0.4758.102, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 98.0.4758.102 (273bf7ac8c90..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.6KFODw}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:40821}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 68fbeff253e6c1d70f858edc8aa8d386
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:452)
    at com.coda.object.Driversetup.closeSession(Driversetup.java:65)
    at com.coda.testcases.Basesetup.teardown(Basesetup.java:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilUnavailable(UrlChecker.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:224)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilUnavailable(UrlChecker.java:115)
    ... 26 more
... Removed 13 stack frames
```

Is this issue because of the system resources being used to their full extent? I observed all the 8 cores of the CPU were showing 100% occupied and memory usage is around 20GB out of 32GB.